# How to fill a shape defined by arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, arc

I have three intersecting arcs, and I want to fill the region inside the intersection points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \tikzstyle{intersection} = [draw, circle ,fill=darkgray, inner sep=0.4mm]
        \draw (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1);
        \draw (0.9414, 0.33728) arc (226:254:1.5);
        \draw (1.58918, 0.04265) arc (102:122:2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

But when I use

```
\fill (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1) (0.9414, 0.33728) arc (226:254:1.5) (1.58918, 0.04265) arc (102:122:2);
```

I get this:

[image]

The arcs are filled through the center of the arc, but I want the complement of this. How can I do it?

I can use a "hack" by filling in the triangle defined by the intersection points, and then filling the arcs white to achieve my goal, but I am highly suspicious that this is a generic solutiuon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the first step: add `--`. The second step is to clip. This yields

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
        \tikzstyle{intersection} = [draw, circle ,fill=darkgray, inner sep=0.4mm]
        \draw[name path=path1] (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1);
        \draw[name path=path2] (0.9414, 0.33728) arc (226:254:1.5);
        \draw[name path=path3] (1.58918, 0.04265) arc (102:122:2);
        \path[name intersections={of=path1 and path2,by=x12}];
        \path[name intersections={of=path2 and path3,by=x23}];
        \path[name intersections={of=path3 and path1,by=x31}];
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (x12)--(x23)--(x31)--cycle;
        \filldraw[draw=black,fill=blue] (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1) -- (0.9414, 0.33728) arc
        (226:254:1.5)-- (1.58918, 0.04265) arc (102:122:2);
        \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I only made the code a bit shorter and changed the fill color, otherwise this is the original code.

Comment: In which order shall I write the arcs?

Comment: It is OK, but did you use that ordering according to some rule, or just arbitrarily?

Comment: I now understood. I have to start drawing the next arc where the previous one is finished. Otherwise, TikZ closes the arc from inside, as you have mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @padawan Yes. I could not have explained this better ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

with help of `backgrounds` and `intersections` libraries:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, intersections}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}[htbp]
%        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
% fill arcs and determine their names
\fill[white, name path=a]   (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1);
\fill[white, name path=b]   (0.9414, 0.33728)   arc (226:254:1.5);
\fill[white, name path=c]   (1.58918, 0.04265)  arc (102:122:2);
% calculate intersections
\path[name intersections={of=a and b, by={ab}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=a and c, by={ac}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=b and c, by={bc}}] ;
% background fill
\scoped[on background layer]\fill[red] (ab) -- (ac) -- (bc) -- cycle; % color determine according to your wish
% drawing arcs agaib
\draw   (0.95572,-0.29428)  arc (-19.41:18.41:1);
\draw   (0.9414, 0.33728)   arc (226:254:1.5);
\draw   (1.58918, 0.04265) arc (102:122:2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```